# merge rows in R and paste the column values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this df

```
          V1         V2         V3                
         7f7e     ASN 440 E  GLY 124 C        
3279     7f7e     ASP 442 E  THR 123 C          
3280     7f7e     ARG 346 E  TYR 119 C          
3281     7f7e     LEU 441 E  GLY 117 C          
3282     7f7e     ASN 440 E  ILE 115 C          
3283     7f7e     ASN 440 E  ALA 125 C       
3284     7f7e     SER 443 E  GLY 124 C          
3285     7f7e     ASP 442 E  TYR 119 C
```

what I'd like to do is to have a df that have only one row for each V2 and in V3 all the values corresponding to V2 in a single string. So, for example

```
V1            V2             V3                                
7f7e     ASN 440 E  GLY 124 C, ILE 115 C, ALA 125 C
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm going to try to answer this, but next time please format your data in a way that it can easily be imported into R, or even cut-and-pasted into Excel. You're missing a line number on the first line, your columns are separated by multiple space characters instead of tabs, V3 isn't actually separated from V2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your data, with tabs separating each column and saved it to a file `stack_overflow.tsv` - it looks like this (cut and pasted from text editor):

```
V1  V2  V3
7f7e    ASN 440 E   GLY 124 C
7f7e    ASP 442 E   THR 123 C
7f7e    ARG 346 E   TYR 119 C
7f7e    LEU 441 E   GLY 117 C
7f7e    ASN 440 E   ILE 115 C
7f7e    ASN 440 E   ALA 125 C
7f7e    SER 443 E   GLY 124 C
7f7e    ASP 442 E   TYR 119 C
```

What you want to do is very easy with the `tidyverse` package: you just `group_by` the variables that make up your unique groups, in this case `V1` and `V2`, and then you can do whatever you want to the remaining variable(s), in a group-wise manner - in this case, concatenating them into a single line with the `paste` command. I am calling `summarize` so that each unique group is collapsed into a single row, and `.groups='drop'` so that the final dataframe is no longer grouped - you may or may not want to do that, depending on what you're planning to do next.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_tsv("stack_overflow.tsv")
df2 <- group_by(df, V1, V2) %>% 
  summarize(V3=paste(V3, collapse=', '), .groups='drop')
print(df2)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  V1    V2        V3                             
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>                          
1 7f7e  ARG 346 E TYR 119 C                      
2 7f7e  ASN 440 E GLY 124 C, ILE 115 C, ALA 125 C
3 7f7e  ASP 442 E THR 123 C, TYR 119 C           
4 7f7e  LEU 441 E GLY 117 C                      
5 7f7e  SER 443 E GLY 124 C
```

Answer (score 0):

in Base R you could do:

```
aggregate(.~V2, df, \(x)toString(unique(x)))[names(df)]

    V1        V2                              V3
1 7f7e ARG 346 E                       TYR 119 C
2 7f7e ASN 440 E GLY 124 C, ILE 115 C, ALA 125 C
3 7f7e ASP 442 E            THR 123 C, TYR 119 C
4 7f7e LEU 441 E                       GLY 117 C
5 7f7e SER 443 E                       GLY 124 C
```